# FileMaker Pro Conditional Relationship Not Working

Tags: relationship, filemaker

When I view table "Invoice Check Groupings" in list or table model, all records from Invoice appear, not just those matching the global field "Blank Invoice Check Grouping"'s value. Why doesn't this relationship condition work? I would expect only records satisfying the condition to be displayed.

Thank you,

Ben

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because **Invoice Check Grouping** is also either a global or an unstored (calculated) field. I'm not sure why, as you say, all records appear, I'd say none should. In any case this relationship won't work, because at least one side of a relationship must have indexed fields.

Answer (score 0):

You really didn't say how you're looking at the data. If you have a layout based on Invoice Group Check it's going to show all records in that table. It looks like you have some sort of self relationship so if you're on invoice and you then want to show the related records you need to use the go to related record script step (show all related records) based on layout Invoice Group Check to see what you're expecting.

Comment: I'm using a layout. Do layouts not respect the filtering applied by the self-join?